# Can I set a retention policy on Lambda function versions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have multiple versions of Lambda functions in AWS. There are versions dated back to more than 2 years which are no longer required.

Is there a way to set retention policy for versions in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The only way to achieve this is to run a script with the logic you need to delete the Lambda function versions you no longer require.

You could run something periodically that would remove the older versions, as discussed here:

https://vipmunot.medium.com/how-to-remove-older-versions-of-lambda-a4415f11a2da

Comment: Hope AWS will add this feature soon.